# Java, main code stops when the thread is started

Tags: java, multithreading

When i start some thread in my program, everything else is stopped.

This is my Thread code...

```
static Thread b1 = new Thread(new Builders());
b1.run();
System.out.println("done");
```

This is the class `Builders`.

```
public class Builders implements Runnable {

    static boolean busy=false;
    Random r = new Random();

    public void run() {
        try{
            busy=true;
            System.out.println("ready");
            Thread.sleep(9999);
            busy=false;
            System.out.println("done");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the program , the thread is started and the program wait for the end of the thread. I thought the main point of the threads is that the code can run simultaneously. Could someone please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because threads are started with `start()`, not `run()`, which simply calls the `run` method on the current thread. So it should be:

```
static Thread b1 = new Thread(new Builders());
b1.start();
System.out.println("done");
```

Comment: @backman: Don't forget to accept answers that solve your problem. It's an important part of using SO.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are not starting a thread - instead, you are executing thread's code *synchronously* by calling `run()`; you need to call `start()` instead.

Better yet, you should use [*executors*](http://www.baptiste-wicht.com/2010/09/java-concurrency-part-7-executors-and-thread-pools/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `start()` method. The internal code of Thread will start a new operating system thread that calls your `run()` method. By calling `run()` yourself, you're skipping the thread-allocation code, and just running it in your current Thread.